# Download all versions of files in SP document library without using PowerShell

Tags: document-library

I am able to find a simple solution to download all file versions within a SharePoint document library using a PowerShell script with system admin credentials.  However, I do not have the access needed to run that script and need an alternative method.

Is there a script or method someone can show me to download all versions of all files within a SharePoint document library?

I have reviewed all of the similar solutions found on this site, but all of which either require the use of SharePoint PowerShell or administrative access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access every file in a site collection your account must be a site collection admin or above, otherwise some of the content could be hidden due to permissions
So I'll say no, there is no alternative

Comment: That's fair and might very well be the final answer.  The only additional info I can give is that I have access to download these files and all of their versions manually.  I am an owner of the particular location where these files are located, however, I cannot run SharePoint powershell.  Excuse my ignorance as I may be confusing terms.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking to download them without a powershell and in second sentence you are asking about script? If you cant use PS, you must download them manually, cause you must use some code like CSOM, PS PNP cmds, etc for downloading them. Or just prepare the script(or find it) and send it to your IT specialist for complete the job.